# Datatable saying "No data available in table" even though there is data in the table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular6

Actaully I have the data that are fetched through api and are being displayed in datatable in angular.I need to show the two tables in same html page so I have used two datatables but in one of those table I get "No data available in table". If i use single table then there is not this problem.

component.ts file

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,private assignmentAuditService: AssignmentAuditService,private selectionService: SelectionService,
            private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private chRef1: ChangeDetectorRef,
            private authService:LoginAuthService,private auditGroupService:AuditGroupService) {
            this.authService.isLoggedIn();

               }

          ngOnInit() {

           this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/auditgroup')
              .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
                this.auditorgroups = data;
                console.log(this.auditorgroups);
              });

         //i have called the api to load data into datatable here    this.http.get
('http://localhost:8080/api/selections/getAllNonAuditGroupSelections')
              .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
                this.clients = data;
                console.log(this.clients);

                // You'll have to wait that changeDetection occurs and projects data into 
                // the HTML template, you can ask Angular to that for you ;-)
                this.chRef.detectChanges();

                // Now you can use jQuery DataTables :
                const table: any = $('table');
                this.dataTable = table.DataTable();
              });

              /* for auditgroup selecitonm */

        //i have called the api to load data into datatable here  
     this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/selections/getAllAuditGroupSelections')
              .subscribe((datas: any[]) => {
                this.nonAuditSelection = datas;
                console.log(this.nonAuditSelection);

                // You'll have to wait that changeDetection occurs and projects data into 
                // the HTML template, you can ask Angular to that for you ;-)
                this.chRef1.detectChanges();

                // Now you can use jQuery DataTables :
                const table: any = $('table');
                this.dataTable = table.DataTable();
              });

          }
```

html to display table

```
<h5>Selection Without Audit Group</h5>
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bodered">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Selection No</th>
              <th>SelectionDate</th>
              <th> SelectedBy</th>
              <th>PanEximNumber</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>PhoneNumber</th>
              <th>SelectionType</th>
              <!-- <th>Action</th> -->

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let client of clients" (click)="onClick(client)">
              <td  [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.selectionId}}</td>
              <!--*ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngClass]="{'myclass2': client.auditorGroup,  'myclass1': !client.auditorGroup}"-->
              <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.selectionDate}}</td>
              <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.selectedBy}}</td>
              <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.panEximNumber}}</td>
              <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.name}}</td>
              <td>{{client.address}}</td>
              <td>{{client.phoneNumber}}</td>
              <td>{{client.selectionType}}</td>
             <!--  <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">Edit
              Delete</td> -->

            </tr>


          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="card-body">

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bodered">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Selection No</th>
              <th>SelectionDate</th>
              <th> SelectedBy</th>
              <th>PanEximNumber</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>PhoneNumber</th>
              <th>SelectionType</th>
              <!-- <th>Action</th> -->

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let nonAudit of nonAuditSelection">
              <td>{{nonAudit.selectionId}}</td>
              <!--*ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngClass]="{'myclass2': client.auditorGroup,  'myclass1': !client.auditorGroup}"-->
              <td>{{nonAudit.selectionDate}}</td>
              <td>{{nonAudit.selectedBy}}</td>
              <td>{{nonAudit.panEximNumber}}</td>
              <td>{{nonAudit.name}}</td>
              <td>{{nonAudit.address}}</td>
              <td>{{nonAudit.phoneNumber}}</td>
              <td>{{nonAudit.selectionType}}</td>
             <!--  <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">Edit
              Delete</td> -->

            </tr>


          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Table is diplayed as :

[image]

The api datas are coming right as here is no problem :

[image]

Comment: Can't get your problem correctly.. As in image we could able to see the two separate datas coming for two tables respectively.. In table one you were getting the values but in addition you are getting the ```no data available in table``` right??

Comment: yes the values coming in two tables are from two different api's

Comment: in one table it is showing data plus all things properly but where in another table it is showing me no data available in table

Comment: From where that text ```no data``` is comming from api or you gave it manually??

Comment: No No jquery will detect the no of values and show them automatcially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the jQuery selector you are using, try this:

1. Add `id` to each table as below:

   `<table id="table1" class="table table-bodered">`

   `<table id="table2" class="table table-bodered">`
2. In your .ts change selector as below for the relevant api data to show:

   `const table: any = $('#table1');`

   `const table: any = $('#table2');`

Currently, as you are always selecting a table: `$('table)` jquery selects one table and renders data to it. Hope it helps.